# Unable to connect com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver in JasperStarter

Tags: jdbc, jasperstarter

I have created jasper report using IReport software in which I am using MS-SQL server for Database table data.
When I use JasperStarter to automate my report generation in 'PDF' format, I am unable to get DB related features like table.
like:

```
java -jar lib/jasperstarter.jar pr D:\Development\FOCUS\JapserIReportFiles\DQReport.jasper -f pdf
```

is creating report without DB related tables.

Then I use following command:

```
java -jar lib/jasperstarter.jar pr D:\Development\FOCUS\JapserIReportFiles\DQReport.jasper -t generic -u devuser -f pdf -H smd-gug-sql1 -n Analytics_MDM --db-driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --db-url jdbc:sqlserver://smd-gug-sql1:1433
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I also tried to add sqljdbc4 jar in my lib folder of jasperStarter, but It didnt work either.

Please let me know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

use `--jdbc-dir` to set the directory of sqljdbc4 jar

```
java -jar lib/jasperstarter.jar pr D:\Development\FOCUS\JapserIReportFiles\DQReport.jasper -t generic -u devuser -f pdf -H smd-gug-sql1 -n Analytics_MDM --jdbc-dir directory_of_sqljdbc4/sqljdbc4.jar --db-driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --db-url jdbc:sqlserver://smd-gug-sql1:1433
```

Comment: Its working just by indicating the directory of sqljdbc4.jar file, Thanks :)

Comment: @Deepak if the solution works, please  accept the answer. Thankz :)